# How to write the data to excel with python and keep excel number format?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I'm trying to write the time data into excel with python (I'm using Pandas). When I write time data to excel I have excel number format 'General':

Sample Screenshot
[image: Existing Screenshot]

But I need to have the number format as 'Time' - which I have when I paste the data **as values** manually to the excel file.
Is it possible to do the same with python? If yes how can I do it?

I have tried to change the values into DateTime object but when I write the data it always deletes cells format in excel file

```py
df['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['starttime']).dt.strftime('%I:%M:%S %p')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Pandas?

> **Writing Excel Files Using Pandas**
>
> We'll be storing the information we'd like to write to an Excel file
> in a DataFrame. Using the built-in to_excel() function, we can extract
> this information into an Excel file.*

- Step 1: install pandas in your py env

`pip install pandas`

- Step 2: let's import the Pandas module:

`import pandas as pd`

- Step 3:
  use the to_excel() function to write the contents to a file. The only argument is the file path:

`df.to_excel('./states.xlsx')`

Comment: I'm already using pandas, and it changes the excel number type to general and I need to have the number type "time".